# Connection Refused

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I am running bitcoind in unbuntu 16.04. And a web server running in docker container. When I excuted curl in container bash 
`curl --user user:pass --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","method":"getblockchaininfo","params":[]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:18332/`

response is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 18332: Connection refused`

docker inner address 172.17.0.1
. However, curl in command line directly is ok.

Below is .conf setting:

`server=1
testnet=1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
rpcallowip=172.17.0.1
rpcport=18332
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1`

I have tried all possible combinations of ip address and port number. All the results are 'Connection refused'
Can anyone advise me how to resolve the problem?
Thanks

Regards, Max

Answer (score 4):

Since Bitcoin Core 0.17 certain config file options are net-specific. In particular this is true for `rpcport`.

This means you need to write it as `test.rpcport=18332` now.

More information can be found in the 0.17 release notes: https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.17.0/ (look for "Configuration sections for testnet and regtest").

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I don't think it is the reason why I can't connect bitcoind daemon from docker.

Answer (score -1):

in the versions 0.15+ bitcoind rpc require `rpcauth` in the `bitcoin.conf` file.

```
rpcauth = user: password //generated with python script
```